Issue with Loading CSS and JS Files in WebView from MAUI Resources Folder
I am building a .NET MAUI app and am trying to render an HTML file in a WebView. The HTML file needs to load external CSS and JavaScript files that are located in the Resources/FirecodeRequirements folder of my MAUI project.
I’ve followed the steps to include the assets, but they are not loading correctly in the WebView. Here are the details of my setup:
Folder Structure:
/Resources
    └── /FirecodeRequirements
        ├── index.html
        ├── styles.css
        └── script.js


Build Action:

I've set the Build Action for all the files (index.html, styles.css, script.js) to MauiAsset.

HTML File (index.html):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fire Code Requirements</title>
    <!-- Correct Path to CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="FirecodeRequirements/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table_component page active">
        <table>
            <tr><th>Page 1</th></tr>
            <tr><td>Content for page 1</td></tr>
        </table>
        <div class="navigation-btns">
            <button class="prevBtn" disabled>Previous</button>
            <button class="nextBtn">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Correct Path to JS -->
    <script src="FirecodeRequirements/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


MAUI Code to Load the HTML:
var webView = new WebView
{
    Source = "Resources/FirecodeRequirements/index.html"
};


Problem:

The HTML is loading correctly, but CSS and JavaScript are not applied (styles and scripts are not working).
-I’ve tried different variations of the file paths but the CSS and JS files still aren’t loading.

What I’ve Tried:

Ensured the Build Action for the CSS, JS, and HTML files is set to MauiAsset.
Made sure the paths in the HTML file are correct and reflect the folder structure (FirecodeRequirements/).
Cleaned and rebuilt the project.
Verified the app is running correctly on the device, but the styles and scripts are not applied.

Question:
How can I correctly load CSS and JavaScript files from the Resources folder into a WebView in .NET MAUI? Is there a specific way to reference the asset files that I might be missing?
Any guidance on what could be going wrong would be much appreciated!

try:
<script src="../FireCodeRequirements/scripts.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../FirecodeRequirements/styles.css">


i tried this, and it solved my problem.
now i know that ../ move up from your current directory.

The ../ at the beginning of the path moves up one directory from the location of the HTML file. So this path works if the HTML file is located in a subdirectory that has a sibling directory named FirecodeRequirements containing styles.css.
